# Understanding the runtime difference of list vs dict

Tags: python, list, dictionary, runtime, python-3.5

I was studying for my test and stumbled upon this:

The question is: Which algorithm is the **fastest**, which is the **slowest**.

```
def f1():
    a = []
    for j in range(100000):
        a.append(j*j)

    for j in range(100000):
        if 99999*j == a[j]:
            print("yes")
def f2():
    a = []
    for j in range(100000):
        a.append(j*j)

    for j in range(100000):
        if 99999*j in a:
            print("yes")
def f3():
    d = {}
    for j in range(100000):
        d[j] = j*j

    for j in range(100000):
        if 99999*j in d:
            print("yes")
```

I understood **f2** is the **slowest** because to check if an item is in a list you run over all the members of the list.

Which would run faster? boolean expression: (99999*j == a[j]) or (99999*j in d, where d is a dictionary and uses hash) and why? I thought hash makes everything O(1) so they should be equal.

Thank you.

Comment: In 3 you just check keys and values don't compare

Answer (score 0):

at now with no edit in case 3 you just check for keys not values and perhaps this is mistake. bu if you edit it like

```
def f3():
    d = {}
    for j in range(100000):
        d[j] = j*j
    for j in range(100000):
        if d[j] == 99999*j:
            print("yes")
```

then also function 1 will be faster

Comment: I didn't fully understand what you meant by 'check for keys not values', however, I timed the functions:


f1 - ~0.10704922676086426 seconds
f2 - ~674.6455340385437 seconds
f3 - ~0.11258125305175781 seconds

f1 and f3 differ...  in every iteration,  I imagine they wanted us to say f1 because it doesn't waste time on hashing.

Thank you very your reply